# Make button respond to the Enter Key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my form, and when the button is clicked, it takes the value of a textbox and populates that value into a list.  Usually, when someone hits the enter key on a form, then the form is submitted but I have written this to stop that behavior:

```
$(document).on("keypress",
    "form",
    function(event) {
        return event.keyCode != 13;
    });
```

But, now I would like the functionality of the Enter key to be used for the purpose of the button on the form.  As of now I have this code (based on the click) for it's current functionality:

```
$("#WL-Add-Btn").click(function () {
    var myVal = $("#WL-TxtBox").val();
    console.log(myVal);
    var uid = generateId();
    $("#Weight-Location-Count-List")
        .append("<li data-uid='" + uid + "' data-id='" +
            myVal +
            "' class='list-group-item list-group-item-default text-info mb-1' >" +
            myVal +
            " <button type='button' class='close remove-button'>&times;</button></li>");
    $("#Weigh-Location-Count-ListBox").append("<option data-uid='" +
        uid +
        "' selected='true' value='" +
        myVal +
        "'>" +
        myVal +
        "</option>");
    $("#WL-TxtBox").val("");
});
```

How do I make that button respond to both click and the enter key?

Comment: move the code that you want enter and click code to share and `keyCode` is 13 or a button is clicked. You can also set button `type` to `submit` and move the code to `submit` event listener on a form.

Comment: `type=button` won't submit form

Comment: `<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();"> ` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make the button a `submit`
2. Put it inside a `form` along with the text box
3. Handle the forms submit event instead of the buttons click event
4. Inside your keypress handler, check the target of the event.  If it's the textbox you care about, let the enter go through.

Sample

```
<form id="frm">
    <textarea id="WL-TxtBox"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="WL-Add-Btn">Button</button>
</form>


$(document).on("keypress",
"form",
function(event) {
    return !$(event.target).is($("#WL-TxtBox")) && event.keyCode != 13;
});

$("#frm").submit(function (e) {
var myVal = $("#WL-TxtBox").val();
console.log(myVal);
var uid = generateId();
$("#Weight-Location-Count-List")
    .append("<li data-uid='" + uid + "' data-id='" +
        myVal +
        "' class='list-group-item list-group-item-default text-info mb-1' >" +
        myVal +
        " <button type='button' class='close remove-button'>&times;</button></li>");
$("#Weigh-Location-Count-ListBox").append("<option data-uid='" +
    uid +
    "' selected='true' value='" +
    myVal +
    "'>" +
    myVal +
    "</option>");
$("#WL-TxtBox").val("");

e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that will be called from both the click and the enter key, lets say you called it action().

Then when the button is pressed, do:

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    action()
}
```

And replace the

```
$("#WL-Add-Btn").click(function () {....
```

With

```
$("#WL-Add-Btn").click(action)
```